# How to express the function $a(t)$ knowing a parametrization $a(\eta)$ and $t(\eta)$?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, series-expansion, algebraic-manipulation

I have this function :
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
    a(\eta) = \sqrt{\sin{2 \eta}},
\end{equation}
and this time variable :
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
    t(\eta) = \int_0^\eta a(\eta') \, d\eta'.
\end{equation}
This integral is very difficult to express in an analytical way, because of the square-root.

I would like to know the function $a$ *parametrized as a power series* of $t$.  How can I achieve this ?

When $\eta$ is very small, I could get
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
    a( \, \eta(t) \, ) \approx (3 \, t)^{\frac{1}{3}}.
\end{equation}
When $\eta$ isn't so small, I'm expecting something like this (but I could be wrong) :
\begin{equation}\tag{4}
    a(\, \eta(t) \,) = (3 \, t)^{\frac{1}{3}} f(t),
\end{equation}
where $f(t)$ could be Taylor expanded (?).  How to find this function using ***Mathematica*** ?

---

**EDIT :** To clarify a few things :  I don't know the function $f(t)$ defined above.  This is what I'm looking for, as a Taylor series of $t$.

I can integrate the function (1) to get $t(\eta)$ using ***Mathematica***, as a power expansion :

```
FullSimplify[
    Series[
        Integrate[Sqrt[Abs[Sin[2 x]]], {x, 0, eta}, Assumptions -> 0 < eta < Pi/2],
    {eta, 0, 6}]
]
```

I then get this :
\begin{equation}\tag{5}
 t(\eta) \approx \sqrt{2} \; \eta^{\frac{3}{2}} \big( \frac{2}{3} - \frac{2}{21} \; \eta^2 + \frac{1}{495} \; \eta^4 - \frac{1}{2835} \; \eta^6 \big).
\end{equation}
Then I need to invert this, to get $a(t) \equiv a( \, \eta(t) \, )$, as a power expansion in $t$ (or maybe $t^{1/3}$ ?).  It should be pretty basic.  As I said above, I'm expecting something like
\begin{equation}\tag{6}
a( \, \eta(t) \, ) = (3 \, t)^{\frac{1}{3}} f(t),
\end{equation}
with $f(t)$ an unknown Taylor series.

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify a few things.

Comment: $a(\eta(t))=(3t)^{1/3}f(t)$ makes more sense. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `InverseSeries`:

```
tserieseta=FullSimplify[Series[Integrate[Sqrt[Abs[Sin[2 x]]],{x,0,eta},Assumptions->0<eta<Pi/2],{eta,0,8}]]+O[eta]^10
```

$\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{2} \text{eta}^{3/2}-\frac{2}{21} \sqrt{2} \text{eta}^{7/2}+\frac{1}{495} \sqrt{2} \text{eta}^{11/2}-\frac{\sqrt{2} \text{eta}^{15/2}}{2835}-\frac{67 \text{eta}^{19/2}}{538650 \sqrt{2}}+O\left(\text{eta}^{10}\right)$

```
etaseriest = InverseSeries[tserieseta] /. eta -> t
```

$\frac{1}{2} 3^{2/3} t^{2/3}+\frac{3 t^2}{28}+\frac{999 \sqrt[3]{3} t^{10/3}}{43120}+\frac{837\ 3^{2/3} t^{14/3}}{120736}+\frac{1469583 t^6}{201870592}+O\left(t^{19/3}\right)$

```
Series[Sqrt[Sin[2*etaseriest]], {t, 0, 8}]
```

$\sqrt[3]{3} \sqrt[3]{t}-\frac{3}{14} 3^{2/3} t^{5/3}-\frac{405 t^3}{4312}-\frac{1647 \sqrt[3]{3} t^{13/3}}{60368}-\frac{6911325\ 3^{2/3} t^{17/3}}{706547072}+O\left(t^6\right)$

```
f[t] = %/(3 t)^(1/3)
```

$1-\frac{3}{14} \sqrt[3]{3} t^{4/3}-\frac{135\ 3^{2/3} t^{8/3}}{4312}-\frac{1647 t^4}{60368}-\frac{6911325 \sqrt[3]{3} t^{16/3}}{706547072}+O\left(t^{17/3}\right)$

Comment: Cool !  I already found *by hand* the first two terms only, by approximations : $f(t) \approx 1 - \tfrac{1}{14} \, (3 \, t)^{\frac{4}{3}}$.  I'll study your solution.

Comment: What about changing the trigonometric function to an hyperbolic function ?  $\sin{2 \eta} \rightarrow \sinh{2 \eta}$.  In this case, your code doesn't give any power series, and I'm wondering why.

Comment: It's just that with  `Sinh` the first (integration) step introduces a useless complex phase expression as an overall multiplication factor; if you ignore (strip off) that factor from the first result the rest of the code works fine.

Comment: Then how do you strip off the undesirable factor ?

Comment: Copy the output as 'Input Text' and paste as a new input; then edit out the factor and make the edited input equal to `tserieseta`

Comment: Yes, this is what I've done, but is there a way to do this automatically, in a more general way ?  Anyway, I now have a full answer to my question.  I'll wait a bit before marking your answer as the right one.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just expand `s` in a Taylor series and `Integrate` it?

```
a[s_] = Sqrt[Sin[2 s]];
tApprox[h_, order_] := Integrate[Series[a[s], {s, 0, order}], {s, 0, h}]
tExact[h_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[a[s], {s, 0, h}]
```

Then:

```
tApprox[h, 1]
tApprox[h, 3]
(* 2/3 Sqrt[2] h^(3/2) *)
(* -(2/21) Sqrt[2] h^(3/2) (-7 + h^2) *)
```

and

```
p1 = Plot[tExact[h], {h, 0, π/2}];
Show[p1, Plot[Evaluate[tApprox[h, 1]], {h, 0, π/2}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
Show[p1, Plot[Evaluate[tApprox[h, 3]], {h, 0, π/2}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

Comment: @Cham. I am currently working on making this work to yield `a` as a series in `t`, but it's tricky...

Comment: I already integrated the Taylor expansion of $a(\eta)$, to get $t(\eta)$.  But then, I don't know how to invert the series to get $a(t)$, instead of $a(\eta)$.  This is exactly my question.

Comment: @Cham. It would be useful, then, to put what you've done (formatted in *Mathematica* code) in your OP.

Comment: @Cham. Just to clarify: you already know how to get the series expansion of `f[t]`, right? You're actually looking for a way to get a closed form expression for `f`? Actually, now I'm really confused by your question: either you know that `3^(2/3) t^(2/3) f[t] == Sqrt[Sin[2 t]]`, so you can solve for `f` to get the closed form expression, or you solve for `f` and Taylor expand `f` in `t` using `Series`. Is that all you want to do?

Comment: No, I don't know $f(t)$ !  This is exactly what I'm looking for !  I'll edit the question.

Comment: @Cham. But you can *solve* $a(t)=(3t)^{1/3}f(t)$ for $f$! $f(t) = \sqrt{\sin(2t)}/(3t)^{1/3}$.

Comment: I've edited the question.  I think it should be very clear now.

Answer (score 0):

This code works, except that it doesn't give the full answer.  A part is missing :

```
time[eta_] := FullSimplify[
    Series[
        Integrate[Sqrt[Abs[Sin[2 x]]], {x, 0, eta}, Assumptions -> 0 < eta < Pi/2],
    {eta, 0, 6}]]

Eta[t_] := (3 t/(2 Sqrt[2]))^(2/3)  (* This isn't the final function! *)

a[t] := Series[Sqrt[Sin[2 Eta[t]]], {t, 0, 6}]

time[eta]

a[t]
```

This code need a fix :  the function Eta[t] should be the *inversion* of time[eta].  How to do this ?